# What is the purpose of TransitName in Chisel3?

Tags: chisel

In the implementation of the Queue in chisel3,

Object Queue returns **TransitName**:

```
object Queue
{
  /** Create a queue and supply a DecoupledIO containing the product. */
  @chiselName
  def apply[T <: Data](
      enq: ReadyValidIO[T],
      entries: Int = 2,
      pipe: Boolean = false,
      flow: Boolean = false): DecoupledIO[T] = {
    if (entries == 0) {
      val deq = Wire(new DecoupledIO(enq.bits))
      deq.valid := enq.valid
      deq.bits := enq.bits
      enq.ready := deq.ready
      deq
    } else {
      require(entries > 0)
      val q = Module(new Queue(chiselTypeOf(enq.bits), entries, pipe, flow))
      q.io.enq.valid := enq.valid // not using <> so that override is allowed
      q.io.enq.bits := enq.bits
      enq.ready := q.io.enq.ready
      TransitName(q.io.deq, q)
    }
}
```

I couldn't grasp what's inside **TransitName**, because I couldn't understand its meaning of source code.

At the line located at `TransitName(q.io.deq, q)`, I think that just returning q.io.deq(instead of **TransitName**), it works correctly. But why do we need **TransitName**??

Answer (score 1):

`TransitName` is helping to name the created `Queue` module based on what the user specifies. The `Queue` factory creates a new `Queue` object internally, but only returns a portion of its IO. Chisel knows what to name the IO based on the name of the user's val (or via some name override). However, Chisel *does not know* what to name the Queue. For improved readability of the queue in downstream representations (FIRRTL, Verilog), this will "transit" the name of the `q.io.deq` to the `Queue` as opposed to giving it a generated/temporary name (e.g., `_T_42`) that loses the connection to the user's name.

From the perspective of functionality, however, all that `TransitName` is doing is returning `q.io.deq`.

Take a look at the [`TransitName` object definition](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/7de30c2b893a3f24d43f2e131557430eb64f6bc8/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/TransitName.scala) for some more details (and a nice comment).

Comment: I should add that the functionality of TransitName is better provided now by the `@chiselName` annotation